# Seeing ticket allocation before paying on Nightjet

Tags: trains, tickets, family, seating, night-transport

I am booking for a family of 5 to travel on a NightJet service Amsterdam-Munich. There are limited options available (no couchettes and no option to book whole compartment). I am happy to book the 3-bed sleeper compartments (only option available) but prior to paying it comes up with a warning that passengers have not been placed in the same compartment. It is not clear if this means our family will be split across 2 compartments (obviously given we are 5 and they are 3-bed compartments) or whether it means we will be split individually. I obviously don't want my children being in a compartment with strangers by themselves if we are split across 5 compartments for example. I am most concerned as my young teens are classified as adults with the age system used on the NightJet site. Is there anyway to see what compartments have been allocated PRIOR to paying for the non-refundable tickets?

Comment: What date is your travel? For 5 persons what I would book is one 3 bed and one 2 bed compartment.